# JSDoc @property to Typescript declaration

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, type-declaration

I'm creating declaration files for an existing javascript library. One of the classes looks like this:

```
/**
 * Example class
 * @property {Number} realProperty - Is actually defined in the code
 * @property {Number} fakeProperty - Not actually present in the code
 */
export class ExampleClass {
  /**
   * Creates the class
   * @param {Number} inputNumber the number to store
   */
  constructor (inputNumber) {
    this.realProperty = inputNumber
  }
}
```

(the `fakeProperty` is added elsewhere, with an `Object.defineProperty`; for the curious, [this is the real code](https://github.com/RonenNess/Shaku/blob/main/lib/utils/color.js#L391))

The output of `jsdoc` documents both properties. However, when I generate the declaration files via

```
tsc index.js --declaration --allowJs --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir types
```

only the `realProperty` is present (with a `Number` type, so I'm certain the JSDoc is not ignored).

I've been trying several fixes, such as creating a `namespace` for `ExampleClass` elsewhere and adding the `fakeProperty` there, but with all paths I run into the same issue: TypeScript will ignore JSDoc comments when they don't have any associated code.

Are there any solutions, or workarounds?

Comment: Why do you need to add the other property later?

Comment: In the real code, there is a long list of strings (all the CSS color names) that are automatically added as getters for a Color class. Having the actual getter code for each one would add hundreds of lines to the class declaration; having it as fake properties makes it the best case of a single line per color.